# Hazelcast IMap getAll vs getAsync

Tags: hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

In a heavily loaded system being pounded with a very high number of requests such that hazelcast client and server are running on different VM's.

1) Which approach is better to use in terms of response times,
fetching data from IMap using getAll
or
fetching data from IMap  iterating over keys and using getAsync and then using future to store the retrieved data.

2) When does retrieval of data actually happen in case of getAsync? When future is invoked or when getAsync is called?

3) Which of the two should perform better when backoff is disabled?

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb you need to minimize network trips in a distributed system. So `getAll()` is better which sends one operation per partition instead of `get()` which will send one operation over the network per each key.

2) It may or may not be executed before calling `future.get()`, but it will block and will get the result when you call it if the result is still not there.